# Automating Outlook offline / online

Tags: vba, outlook

Most of my tasks are done via Outlook 2016 ie most of the work I do is composing and responding to emails. If I don't switch Outlook offline, I get distracted from the constant inflow. And often times, within an hour or so I don't need to respond because the task has been dealt with.

I can switch Outlook offline /online manually, but I was wondering if there was a Macro that would automate this.

My schedule is as follows

7am Online
8:45 Offline
10:45 Online
10:50 Offline
12:45 Online
12:50 Offline
14:30 Online
14:35 Offline
15:55 Online
16:00 Offline
16:55 Online
17:00 Offline

with the ability to manually override?

Is this possible?

I can do basic Excel macros, but I've never made an Outlook macro

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Diane at Slipstick , and a little bit of my own work, I've found a solution. See https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/95555-vba-to-switch-outlook-online-offline/

There are three sets of macros - one to switch offline, one to switch online, and then a macro to assign a task for the scheduling. The first two macros are here, the third you can find in the forum reference above.

Hope this helps someone

```
Sub SetOffline()

Dim oNS As NameSpace
Set oNS = Application.Session

If oNS.ExchangeConnectionMode <> olCachedOffline And _
oNS.ExchangeConnectionMode <> olOffline Then

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objExpl As Outlook.Explorer
Set olApp = Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objExpl = olApp.ActiveExplorer

objExpl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToggleOnline")

End If

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub OnlineStatus()
Dim oNS As NameSpace
Set oNS = Application.Session

If oNS.ExchangeConnectionMode = olOnline

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objExpl As Outlook.Explorer
Set olApp = Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objExpl = olApp.ActiveExplorer

objExpl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ToggleOnline")

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) - you can use [IMAPIOfflineMgr::SetCurrentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905141(v=office.12).aspx). 
In case of other languages besides C++ or Delphi, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Offline` property:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Session.Offline = true
```

Keep in mind however that `IMAPIOfflineMsg` interface cannot be marshaled between different processes (e.g. outlook.exe and excel.exe), so neither `IMAPIOfflineMgr` nor `RDOSession.Offline` would work from Excel VBA. You can try to simulate a click on the "Work Offline" button using either Accessibility API or, again, using Redemption and its [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object:

```
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
set Ribbon =  sExplorer.Ribbon
oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab
Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Send / Receive"
set Control = Ribbon.Controls("Work Offline")
Control.Execute
Ribbon.ActiveTab = oldActiveTab 'restore the active tab
```